# Manual Scaling of Nodes on a deployed Vertex AI endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops

I have a deployed endpoint on Vertex AI with auto-scaling being enabled. But I want to manually adjust the min-replicas and max-replicas for the deployed endpoint. How to do so?

I was usiong this command from console, but the flags "min-replicas" & "max-replicas" aren't available for the updaet command:

gcloud ai endpoints update #{model_name} --update-deployment #{model_name} --min-replica-count=#{new_node_count} --max-replica-count=#{new_node_count}